# how to use inside mysql with laravel if for each product supported languages with some nested supported info ... see to understand

Tags: mysql, laravel, nested

am using laravel with (mysql)... what i want to do is same like this:

```
for each product->>>
       langs 
          english:
             interface: true,
             subtitles: false,
             interface: true,
          ,
          arabic:
             interface: false,
             subtitles: true,
             interface: true,
          ,
          .........
          .........
```

but with... ( Each language has its own products, such as one tag or else )

am expecting to get each product with supported langs with this example above about nested info for each lang row

Please be clear in your response with ( laravel or mysql or any tool make the idea clear

Comment: have you made your tables yet ?

Comment: no, not yet.. why ( am just want the idea to do this only and will continue alone

Comment: make languages, products, and language_product tables.
language_product will be a pivot table and will have belongsToMany relationship and then can achieve what you want. There may be some other ways but this comes in my mind.
if you want I can write in detail in answer section

Comment: so you can, and i will try if work, but please make idea more clear when explain in answer, thank you very much

Comment: sure i will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language Model

```
class Language extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'language_product')
            ->withPivot('interface', 'subtitles');
    }
}
```

Product Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class, 'language_product')
            ->withPivot('interface', 'subtitles');
    }
}
```

your pivot table language_product will have the product id and language id and the other fields like interface, subtitles, etc. and you can fetch it withPivot in the relationship

You can now retrieve each product with its supported languages.

```
$products = Product::with('languages')->get();

foreach ($products as $product) {
  
   foreach ($product->languages as $language) {
       
   }
}
```

you can read more from here [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns)